# LibreOffice Calc: Formula does not recalculate

Tags: libreoffice

I created a new spreadsheet with LibreOffice 6.4 and noticed that formulas do not execute (and recalculate). So, when I write =1+1 or =A1+A2 (with values in those cells), nothing happens. Likewise, when I copy and paste formulas from older spreadsheets, nothing happens either.

I have found some advice in various forums that point to Tools->Options and LibreOffice->Preferences (since I have a Mac). One source tells me that auto-recalculation is disabled for reasons of backward compatibility with Excel (what I do not understand as I just created a new file).

I have enabled 'Always recalculate' for both options in LibreOffice->Preferences (Option LibreCalc->Formula):

[image: Option to always recalculate]

Nothing in the 'Calculate' Option tab seems to indicate anything in this direction.

This seems not to change anything. What am I missing?

How can I make sure that everything always recalculates and always executes all my formulas?

Thanks!

Comment: You should also check `View` under the menu you show there and make sure `Display:Formulas` is not checked.
FWIW, I'm having a similar problem to you though in Linux Ubuntu 19.10, Libreoffice 6.3.5.2.  When I type `=A1`, that's just what it prints in the cell rather than the contents of A1.  =1+1 does work correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select your range ; hit CTRL+H ; Found = ^. ; Replace = & ; check "regular expressions" box below ; "replace all" button;
```

It works better if you create a new empty spreadsheet and then paste your data.

Comment: What is that find+replace supposed to do? It looks like "replace contents of every non-blank cell with ampersand character".

Answer (score 0):

What worked today under Windows only: Re-create the formula in a new column. After it works correctly, Copy or Move the new cell into the old position, overwriting everything in the cell that was not calculating.